Why are my Firebase RTDB Rules Always Returning Unauthorized
Rules
{
  "rules": {
    "Accounts": {
      ".read": "true",
      "$user_id": {
        // Check if object has all required values after operation
        ".validate": "newData.child('Username').isString() && 
                      newData.child('Password').isString() && 
                      newData.child('Salt').isString() && 
                      newData.child('ExpirationDate').isString()",
        // Only allow username update if:
        //  * There is a provided username AND
        //  * There is no existing username (new account) OR
        //  * It is the same as the existing username (patches)
        "Username": {
          ".write": "(!data.exists() || data.val() === newData.val())"
        },
        "Password":         {".write": "newData.exists()"},
        "Salt":             {".write": "newData.exists()"},
        "ExpirationDate":   {".write": "newData.exists()", ".validate": "newData.isString()"},
        "IsVerified":       {".write": "newData.exists()", ".validate": "newData.isBoolean()"},
        "Domains":          {".write": "true"},
        "ActiveDomain":     {".write": "true"},
        "VerificationCode": {".write": "!data.exists() || newData.exists()", ".validate": "newData.isString()"}
      },
    }
  }
}

The POST Sent
Sent to [FIREBASEURL]/Accounts/blmvyubcyhislpquhj@ytnhy,com.json
{
  "Username": "blmvyubcyhislpquhj@ytnhy,com",
  "Password": "lR3lh7BcXU0=",
  "Salt": "0sFEiXUsUpQ=",
  "ExpirationDate": "8/1/2024",
  "ActiveDomain": null,
  "Domains": null,
  "IsVerified": false,
  "VerificationCode": "327761"
}

This POST always returns Unauthorized.
From what I've found, the rules work if I remove all the "Username" level rules and replace it with a dummy ".write":"true".
I've tried with lowercase field names.
I've tried just the username rule at that level.
The playground seems to show that the request is valid.
I'd like to avoid using Firebase Authentication if possible. I realize it'll be less secure this way.

All of your rules are nested under the rule for ""Accounts". Move the rules one level up (not nested inside Accounts) and it should work.

But if I'm sending the request to url.com/Accounts/USERID, shouldn't it be fine?

Sending a POST request creates a new child under the path where you call it. So you're writing the JSON to [FIREBASEURL]/Accounts/blmvyubcyhislpquhj@ytnhy,com/newpushID, which your rules don't allow.
To fix this, use PUT rather than POST.
These are normal RESTful semantics btw, so I recommend reading up on those.

You're also not granting anyone write access to [FIREBASEURL]/Accounts/blmvyubcyhislpquhj@ytnhy,com, but only to [FIREBASEURL]/Accounts/blmvyubcyhislpquhj@ytnhy,com/Username. So writing on the [FIREBASEURL]/Accounts/blmvyubcyhislpquhj@ytnhy,com gets rejected.
Fix this by having a .write rule on the [FIREBASEURL]/Accounts/blmvyubcyhislpquhj@ytnhy,com level in your rules that evaluates to true for the PUT request. The .write rules you currently have on levels below that should probably be .validate rules.

That's... a very good point.
I just tried the same with PUT but had no luck either.
I've been doing it in Postman
https://imgur.com/a/SiPkeZA
Though it fails as well in my real app.

Added a second problem to my answer.

That seems to be working! I added a ".write":"true" at the end and changed all my write rules to validate rules.
Much appreciated!
